# Rotating image based on drag handle in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing

My end goal is to achieve somethinng like this:

[image]

As you can see there's the drag handle is required to rotate this image.

I have a following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

double ballRadius = 7.5;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double _angle = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 100,
                left: 100,
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: _angle,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        ),
                        child: LayoutBuilder(
                          builder: (context, constraints) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                              onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                                Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(
                                  constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                                  constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                                );
                                final touchPositionFromCenter =
                                    details.localPosition -
                                        centerOfGestureDetector;
                                print(touchPositionFromCenter.direction);
                                setState(() {
                                  _angle = touchPositionFromCenter.direction;
                                });
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 30,
                        width: 5,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It is working. But sometimes it's too fast or too slow. Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made a few modifications to the code, notably

1. Treating the "real" `centerOfGestureDetector` as the center of all the items you would like to rotate
2. Determining and tracking the change in angle with the `onPanStart`,`onPanEnd` and `onPanUpdate` methods

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

double ballRadius = 7.5;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double _angle = 0.0;
  double _oldAngle = 0.0;
  double _angleDelta = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 100,
                left: 100,
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: _angle,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        ),
                        child: LayoutBuilder(
                          builder: (context, constraints) {
                            //   Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(
                            // constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2);
                            /**
                           * using center of positioned element instead to better fit the
                           * mental map of the user rotating object.
                           * (height = container height (30) + container height (30) + container height (200)) / 2
                           */
                            Offset centerOfGestureDetector =
                                Offset(constraints.maxWidth / 2, 130);
                            return GestureDetector(
                              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                              onPanStart: (details) {
                                final touchPositionFromCenter =
                                    details.localPosition -
                                        centerOfGestureDetector;
                                _angleDelta = _oldAngle -
                                    touchPositionFromCenter.direction;
                              },
                              onPanEnd: (details) {
                                setState(
                                  () {
                                    _oldAngle = _angle;
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                                final touchPositionFromCenter =
                                    details.localPosition -
                                        centerOfGestureDetector;

                                setState(
                                  () {
                                    _angle = touchPositionFromCenter.direction +
                                        _angleDelta;
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 30,
                        width: 5,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```